# About this big list of tag edits

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-wiki

This user just made [many tag editions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/744859/jav-rock?tab=activity&sort=revisions), describing such tags as [angle](/questions/tagged/angle), [integral](/questions/tagged/integral), [exponent](/questions/tagged/exponent), and so on.

Does that really make sense?

Do we want wiki documented tags for every dictionary words?

Comment: Most of his edits are lifted whole-sale from Wikipedia..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's quite a bit of plagiarism in those wiki inserts; I rejected a few of those edits myself on the basis of plagiarism.

Thanks for bringing this to our attention.  In the future, please bring it to our attention with a flag on the user's post if you see a user is plagiarizing content from other sites. Choose flag reason 'other', and explain that the user is plagiarizing content.

Comment: I also saw a lot of non specific edits, like the addition of a link to  http://www.developer.nokia.com/ to some nokia related tags

Comment: I was rejecting a few too; any way we can clean up the mess.

Comment: This user is still overloading the edit review system with editions directly copied from wikipedia (the last I saw is "aliasing", which wasn't even correct for to the usage of this tag in SO). Can something be done ?